# Typehinting a function using Mapping,Hashable so that it accepts dictionaries with python Mypy

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to typehint a dictionary which can vary - and thought that `Mapping, Hashable` would work as follows:

```py
from typing import Hashable, Mapping

def f(x : Mapping[Hashable, str]) -> None:
    print(x)
    

_dict = {'hello' : 'something'}

f(x = _dict)
```

errors with:

```
main.py:9: error: Argument "x" to "f" has incompatible type "Dict[str, str]"; expected "Mapping[Hashable, str]"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I don't understand the reason for this error though, I've passed it a dictionary which is a "Mapping" type ? (https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/builtin_types.html). And the keys are hashable, which I thought would be a type of `Hashable`.

When I go through the parts - they all seem ok, so I'm not sure how to solve this / what I've misunderstood.

Answer (score 2):

`Mapping` is [invariant](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/140) (documented [here](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/typing.pyi#L578=)) in key. It means that `Mapping[T1, str]` is a subtype of (`<:`) `Mapping[T2, str]` if and only if `T1` and `T2` refer to the same type, and `T1` being subtype of `T2` does not help. So you can pass only `dict[Hashable, str]` or another mapping with `Hashable` as key type.

The solution here is to [use](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=8afc3ef197f3c08079ebb40f68df967b) `Mapping[Any, str]` and not bother with `Hashable`. This does not reduce type strictness: if key is not `Hashable`, then the mapping will never be constructed and thus cannot be passed to function.

```py
def f(x: Mapping[Any, str]) -> None:
    print(x)


dict_ = {'hello' : 'something'}
f(x = dict_)
```

You can also annotate explicitly to allow this, but then you'll annotate all dictionaries before passing to function, and this is not convenient:

```py
dict_: dict[Hashable, str] = {'hello' : 'something'}
```

Comment: what does `<:` mean ?

Comment: `T1 <: T2` means "`T1` is a subtype of `T2`" (in some contexts "strict subtype", then `<=:` stays for non-strict subtype relation)