# Mypy gives error about incompatible type which is a subset of an expected Union

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Example code :

```py
from typing import Any, Union, Dict


def F(x : Dict[Union[float, int, str], str]) -> None:
    print(x)

def G() -> Dict[Union[float, int], str]:
    return {1 : 'this'}
    
    
g = G()
F(x = g)
```

Gives error :

```
main.py:12: error: Argument "x" to "F" has incompatible type "Dict[Union[float, int], str]"; expected "Dict[Union[float, int, str], str]"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

But from the typing I would expect the output of `G` to be fine as input to `F`, as it's a subset of `F`.

Clearly there's something that I'm not understanding here - but I don't know what it is.

This works fine for example:

```py
from typing import Any, Union, Dict


def f(x : Union[float, int, str]) -> None:
    print(x)
    
def g() -> str:
    return 'this'
    

f(x = g())
```

Which is what I would expect.

If it's a key for a dictionary does `Union` work differently?

Comment: `dict` is invariant in key type. Also, obviously, your case is not type-safe: suppose `f` is doing `x['key'] = 'value'` - it is OK for `dict[float | str, str]`, but invalid for `dict[float, str]`. And `Union[float, int]` is equivalent to bare `float`, `int` is subtype of `float` for mypy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typehinting a function using Mapping,Hashable so that it accepts dictionaries with python Mypy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72841458/typehinting-a-function-using-mapping-hashable-so-that-it-accepts-dictionaries-wi)