# How to type-annotate correctly a custom MutableMapping implementation?

Tags: python, mypy, typing

I've got the following subclassed `MutableMapping`:

```
from typing import Hashable, Any, MutableMapping
from _typeshed import SupportsKeysAndGetItem

class MyMutableMapping(MutableMapping[Hashable, Any]):
    def update(self, other: SupportsKeysAndGetItem[Hashable, Any], /, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        pass
```

However, `mypy` complains about the signature of my overridden `update` method.

```
test.py:5: error: Signature of "update" incompatible with supertype "MutableMapping"  [override]
test.py:5: note:      Superclass:
test.py:5: note:          @overload
test.py:5: note:          def update(self, SupportsKeysAndGetItem[Hashable, Any], /, **kwargs: Any) -> None
test.py:5: note:          @overload
test.py:5: note:          def update(self, Iterable[tuple[Hashable, Any]], /, **kwargs: Any) -> None
test.py:5: note:          @overload
test.py:5: note:          def update(self, **kwargs: Any) -> None
test.py:5: note:      Subclass:
test.py:5: note:          def update(self, SupportsKeysAndGetItem[Hashable, Any], /, **kwargs: Any) -> None
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I went as far duplicating the exact signature that `mypy` claims the superclass has but no luck. What am I doing wrong?

edit: I've gone ahead and submitted an [issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/15816) in the github mypy issues tracker.

Answer (score 0):

> ...duplicating the exact signature that mypy claims the superclass has...

Did you? `overload` is not "one of", it's "all of" when implementing. Your subclass must support at least all three overload variants, not arbitrary one of them. The following typechecks:

```py
from typing import Hashable, Any, Iterable, MutableMapping, overload
from _typeshed import SupportsKeysAndGetItem

class MyMutableMapping(MutableMapping[Hashable, Any]):
    @overload
    def update(self, arg: SupportsKeysAndGetItem[Hashable, Any], /, **kwargs: Any) -> None: ...
    @overload
    def update(self, arg: Iterable[tuple[Hashable, Any]], /, **kwargs: Any) -> None: ...
    @overload
    def update(self, /, **kwargs: Any) -> None: ...
    
    def update(self, arg: Any = None, /, **kwargs: Any) -> None: ...
```

[Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=887140b4426d59b46f9b08fe1c781783)

I'm not sure why pos-only marker is needed in 3rd overload, but `mypy` considers implementation incompatible with 3rd overload otherwise. Pyright does not, so it may be a `mypy` bug.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72841458/typehinting-a-function-using-mapping-hashable-so-that-it-accepts-dictionaries-wi) for `Hashable` usage as mapping key - may be not worth it.

Comment: The positional-only marker is needed in the third overload because without it, `MyMutableMapping.update(self=some_instance, a=2)` matches the third overload, but is not accepted by the concrete implementation.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks! I thought about this, but it isn't in line with how `mypy` handles `self` in other places - e.g. [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=9e4306d9cbfd506f438cf31894685e3c) is allowed, though `B` violates LSP if we take passing `self` as kwarg into account.

Comment: Yeah, the signature with the `/` also fails to match the reported superclass signature. mypy seems to special-case `self` when checking if a subclass method is compatible with what it overrides, but not when checking overloads.

Comment: (I'm not sure where those positional-only markers in the reported superclass signature are coming from - they're not in the type stub files in either the mypy-internal copy of typeshed or the standalone version of typeshed.)

Comment: @user2357112 note `__m` parameter name. It's a pre-3.8 way to annotate arguments ignoring their name (like positional-only). `mypy` just translates it into modern python.